# Why does a react component render twice?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've placed debuggers in the render of a component and see that it gets ran twice sometimes, if not most of the time. Is it because the first render is before the component receives any props? And the 2nd time is when it receives it? I thought components go through the lifestyle of mounting, receiving props, and then rendering? Or does it mount, render, check props, and then re-render?

Comment: without code we can only guess, my guess is that you're changing the component's state triggering rerenders

Comment: another guess is that your `shouldComponentUpdate` is flawed

Answer (score 7):

Components do not re-render if they have initial props. The only reason that it would re-render is if it is receiving props after the initial render, or if you are changing state.

Comment: In that shouldComponentUpdate should be called, right? But what what if the component renders twice on initial mount without calling shouldComponentUpdate?

Answer (score 1):

In [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64625286/does-it-matter-which-component-i-choose-to-use-in-react?noredirect=1#comment114267600_64625286), I had an issue, and I quote:

> " ...I know that most of these features (and possibly more) are available in function components (introduced most by hooks), but they do not work as I intend them too, because they are NOT exactly the same, like `useEffect(() => {code}, [])` is known to replace `componentDidMount()`, **an yet upon mount it renders twice in any app I develop,** passing false data... "

---

To that issue, [CertainPerformance](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9515207/certainperformance) replied:

> " ...Sounds like you have **strict mode enabled and are performing operations with side-effects, which should be avoided.** You probably just need to figure out the right way to structure the code with functional components - nearly anything you'd want to do can be done reasonably elegantly in functional components, though not absolutely everything... "

---

Which lead me to research a little and find this interesting answer:

> It's an intentional feature of the StrictMode. This only happens in development, and helps find accidental side effects put into the render phase. We only do this for components with Hooks because those are more likely to accidentally have side effects in the wrong place.

You can read more about that on [GitHub](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/15074).