# react - Different random value between parent and child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, rendering, react-component

I face this issue in my real project. To present it more clearly, I built a very basic project, which consists of just a parent and a child component.

I have a random value that I define (no matter if as a state variable or as a 'regular' variable) in the body of the parent component and pass it as props to the child component.
For some reason, when I log (console.log) this random value in the body of the parent component, it appears to be different from the value in the body of the child component. They are equal in the jsx of each component, and when I log the value in an useEffect hook in the parent, but different when I log them in the body of each component.

Parent component:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import ChildComponent from './ChildComponent';

function App() {
  const rand = Math.random();
  console.log('parent - in body', rand);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('parent - in useEffect', rand);    
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>parent {rand}</h1>
      <ChildComponent rand={rand}></ChildComponent>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Child component:

```
import React from 'react';

function ChildComponent(props) {
  console.log('child', props.rand);
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>child {props.rand}</h3>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ChildComponent;
```

The results (the different value in the console is circled):

[image]

Can someone explain this behavior?

---

**UPDATE:**
I realized that the `<React.StrictMode>` in the index.js file was responsible for the re-rendering, hence the different values of the random variable.
However:

- If due to the strict mode the component was rendered twice, why there is only one appearance for each console.log()?
- Is it safe to remove the strict mode to solve this issue (I don't want to lose necessary things on the other hand)?
- Which component was rendered twice (the parent, the child, or both), and how does it works?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my React component is rendering twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48846289/why-is-my-react-component-is-rendering-twice)

Comment: @ManasKhandelwal I don't think so, because in my case according to the console the components render only once (otherwise there would be multiple outputs for each console.log()), and the problem in the post appears to be due to strict mode, which I don't use.

Comment: @ManasKhandelwal My mistake, I indeed used strict mode in the index.js file, and removing it did solve the problem. However, is it safe to remove the strict mode to solve this issue (I don't want to lose necessary things on the other hand)?
And if due to the strict mode the component was rendered twice, why there is only one appearance for each console.log()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably a problem caused for a re-render.

The first value logged is the first generated value, after a re-render appears the new value and this is logged for the `useEffect`, because `useEffect` executes after the component is mounted and the DOM is loaded.

Moreover, the re-render is probably cause for the `<StrictMode>` in your `index.js`, this produce an intentional re-render, to test side-effects and search for problems.

Comment: Thanks - removing the strict mode did solve the problem. However, is it safe to remove the strict mode to solve this issue (I don't want to lose necessary things on the other hand)? And if due to the strict mode the component was rendered twice, why there is only one appearance for each console.log()?

Comment: I don't recommend to you to remove the strict mode, this is a protection to you to avoid a lot of problems. You shouldn't be worried about the re-renders caused by this, that don't will go to affect your program unless your making the things wrong. And probably the answer to all your questions can be founded in this two places. https://es.reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html https://es.reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html