# useEffect doesn't run after rendering

Tags: reactjs, async-await, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

I'm kind of confused about how useEffect is triggered and how it work. I wrote a function like this but the useEffect doesn't run at all. I want to fetch the data from the API and then render a page based on the data. But it doesn't trigger the useEffect. If I don't use the useEffect, it will render the page three times.

```
async function getData() {
  var tmpArrData = [];
  await fetch("this API is hidden due to the privacy of the company - sorry")
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
      console.log("data", data);
      tmpArrData = data;
  });
  console.log("tmpData ", tmpArrData);
  return tmpArrData;
}

function App() {

  const [arrData, setArrData] = useState();
  const [loadData, setLoadData] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("if it works, this line should be shown");
    const tmpArrData = getData();
    setArrData(tmpArrData);
  }, [arrData]);


  const data = arrData[0];
  console.log(data);

  return (
      <GifCompoment 
      id = {data.id}
      name = {data.name}
      activeTimeTo = {data.activeTimeTo}
      activeTimeFrom = {data.activeTimeFrom}
      requiredPoints = {data.requiredPoints}
      imageUrl = {data.imageUrl}
      />
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: The `useEffect` hook is guaranteed to run at least once at the end of the initial render. Are you saying you don't see the `console.log("if it works, this line should be shown");` log?

Comment: yes, I didn't see that line

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `useEffect` hook is guaranteed to run at least once at the end of the initial render.

`getData` is an `async` function and the `useEffect` callback code is not waiting for it to resolve. Easy solution is to chain from the implicitly returned Promise from `getData` and access the resolved value to update the `arrData` state. Make sure to remove the state from the `useEffect`'s dependency array so that you don't create a render loop.

The `getData` implementation could be clean/tightened up by just returning the `fetch` result, no need to save into a temp variable first.

```
async function getData() {
  return await fetch(".....")
    .then((res) => res.json());
}

useEffect(() => {
  console.log("if it works, this line should be shown");
  getData().then((data) => {
    setArrData(data);
  });
}, []); // <-- empty dependency so effect called once on mount
```

Additionally, since `arrData` is initially undefined, `arrData[0]` is likely to throw an error. You may want to provide valid initial state, and a fallback value in case the first element is undefined, so you don't attempt to access properties of an undefined object.

```
const [arrData, setArrData] = useState([]);
```

...

```
const data = arrData[0] || {}; // data is at least an object

return (
  <GifCompoment 
    id={data.id}
    name={data.name}
    activeTimeTo={data.activeTimeTo}
    activeTimeFrom={data.activeTimeFrom}
    requiredPoints={data.requiredPoints}
    imageUrl={data.imageUrl}
  />
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should call state setter insede of `Promise`

```
function App() {
    const [arrData, setArrData] = useState();

    function getData() {
        fetch("/api/hidden")
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((data) => setArrData(data));
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("if it works, this line should be shown");
        getData();
    }, []);

    return ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By combining the answer from Drew Reese and Artyom Vancyan, I have solved my problem. I think the key points are setState right in the then function `.then((data) => setArrData(data))` ,don't put the dependency in the useEffect, and await inside the useEffect. Thank you guy super ultra very much. Big love

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log("if it works, this line should be shown");
    const getData = async () => {
      await fetch("hidden API")
      .then((ref) => ref.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setArrData(data);
      });
    }
    getData();
  }, []);
```

Comment: Secondly, the console log (if it works, this line should be shown) doesn't work because the error while rendering. When I resolve the error, that line was shown

Answer (score -2):

```
function App() {

  const [arrData, setArrData] = useState([]);
  const [loadData, setLoadData] = useState(false);

  
  const async getData=()=> {
  var tmpArrData = [];
  await fetch("this API is hidden due to the privacy of the company - sorry")
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
      console.log("data", data);
      setArrData(tmpArrData);
  });
  console.log("tmpData ", tmpArrData);
  return tmpArrData;
}

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("if it works, this line should be shown");
    const callApi =async()=>{
      await getData();
    } 
  }, [arrData]);


  const data = arrData[0];
  console.log(data);

  return (
      <GifCompoment 
      id = {data.id}
      name = {data.name}
      activeTimeTo = {data.activeTimeTo}
      activeTimeFrom = {data.activeTimeFrom}
      requiredPoints = {data.requiredPoints}
      imageUrl = {data.imageUrl}
      />
  );
}

export default App;
```

Page will be rendered three to four times it's normal.

Comment: "Page will be rendered three to four times it's normal." 
That's not at all normal and will lead to performance issues as you scale.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48846289/why-is-my-react-component-is-rendering-twice


So that might help

Comment: This post has nothing to do with the question. Number of rerenders will always depend on the update in state and props of a component. And if your component is rerendering 3-4 times when you just want to fetch data once, there is some issue with the component. Assuming page rendering 3-4 times is normal is not what you should go for and actually look for the issue.

Comment: Also the solution you have proposed would lead to an infinite loop

Comment: useEffect has deps of [] so this only happens on the first render only. Then you are changing state 2 times, so a re-render happens. This does not mean that the DOM is changed 3 times.

Comment: You have `arrData` as deps and you are calling `setArrData` inside useEffect which will update `arrData` and cause useEffect to run again and this process will keep on going and lead to infnite loop. I didn't say your solution will lead to DOM changing 3 times, you said that page rendering 3-4 times is normal. And you are not even calling `callApi` so actually nothing will happen at all. Have you tried running your own solution?

Comment: No, It will not lead to infinite loop because of this in useEffect [arrData].
Just run useEffect with [arrData] and without [arrData].
You will see diffrence.

Comment: Yes it will if you actually call `callApi`.

Comment: Quick example - https://codesandbox.io/s/mmkck . Check the console

Comment: put a console.log in app.js and check the console