# 'RestConnection Commit failed with error' when trying to write to firestore

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am getting the following error when trying to write to Firestore. This is done in JavaScript(React).Can anyone tell what is this and how  can I fix this?

```
@firebase/firestore: Firestore (8.3.1): RestConnection Commit failed with error:  {"code":"failed-precondition","name":"FirebaseError"} url:  https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/{project name}/databases/(default)/documents:commit request: {"writes":[{"update":{"name":"projects/{project name}/databases/(default)/documents/teams/T22yKl1ERQSlfuZNitrvs2vRjSJ2/team-analytics/T22yKl1ERQSlfuZNitrvs2vRjSJ2-Dec-22-2021","fields":{"homePageViews":{"integerValue":"3"},"timeModified":{"timestampValue":"2021-12-22T09:32:00.000000000Z"}}},"updateMask":{"fieldPaths":["homePageViews","timeModified"]},"currentDocument":{"updateTime":"2021-12-22T09:23:08.916511000Z"}}]}
```

My code that is trying to access Firestore is shown below:

```
return db.runTransaction(async (transaction) => {
    const analyticsDoc = await transaction.get(analyticsReference);

    if (analyticsDoc.exists) {
        const analytics: any = analyticsDoc.data();
        return transaction.update(analyticsReference, { homePageViews: analytics.homePageViews + 1, timeModified: getCurrentDateTime() });
    }
    const newAnalytics: AnalyticsObject = {
        totalViews: 0,
        homePageViews: 1,
        timeModified: getCurrentDateTime(),
    };
    return transaction.set(analyticsReference, newAnalytics);
});
```

I am also getting the following error in my console:

```
POST https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/optimx-sports/databases/(default)/documents:commit 400
```

Edit: After more digging in, I am thinking it might be because I am sending 2 transactions to the same document simultaneously. Is it possible that this error is because of this?

Comment: How are you trying to access Firestore? please share code and details so we can provide a better solution.

Comment: Added code and some more details above

Comment: @MonaliGhotekar please let me know if you need any more info

Comment: Are you trying to get analytic data as mentioned in code "homePageViews: analytics.homePageViews"?

Comment: Its a transaction which fetches the current analytics data, increments by 1 and commits it again to firestore

Comment: A few points you can check with:

In Cloud Firestore, you can only update a single document about once per second, which might be too low for some high-traffic applications. Have a look at https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/counters from the Firestore documentation.
You can refer to the support documentation for Firestore https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/troubleshooting#latency.
Also You can try with the Postman API https://www.postman.com/ to access data.

Comment: That's what I thought. Alright, I guess that solves it.

Comment: I have posted the above comment in the answer section. If my answer addressed your question, please consider accepting and up-voting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below are a few Points you can check with:

1. In Cloud Firestore, you can only update a single document about once
   per second, which might be too low for some high-traffic
   applications. Have a look at [Firestore documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/counters).
2. You can refer to the [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/troubleshooting#latency).
3. Also You can try with [Postman API](https://www.postman.com/) to access data.
4. Another way is combining two commits as well.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was making a transaction commit inside a hook and React was rendering my component twice. This was too much for Firestore to handle.

The solution was to disable strict mode for React:

```
// index.js

// good 
root.render(<App/>); ✅

// bad
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App/>
  </React.StrictMode>
); ❌
```

## References

https://stackoverflow.com/a/65167384/17627866

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I was sending two transaction commits to one firestore document within a second. The second commit was raising the above error. Fixed it by combining the two commits