# Selector returns previous value

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I have a redux-toolkit slice with a 'loading' state value that is initially set to `idle`.
When dispatching a `createAsyncThunk` action, the `loading` state value is updated to `pending`, and I can observe that the state is updated correctly from the Redux dev tools.
The dispatch is called inside a useEffect with the value from the `loading` selector in the dependency array.
I test that the value is equal to 'idle' before dispatching the action. But somehow, the action is dispatched at least twice (many more times in my code). Why ?
It looks like the selector is not picking up the state change.

Here is a minimal reproducible example sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-sammet-0smieb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the [behavior](https://reactjs.org/blog/2022/03/29/react-v18.html#new-strict-mode-behaviors) of the `StrictMode` component.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (loading === "idle") {
      console.count(loading);
      dispatch(getSomething());
    }
  }, [loading, dispatch]);
```

With the `StrictMode` component, the logs:

```
idle: 1 
idle: 2
```

Without the `StrictMode` component, the logs:

```
idle: 1
```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-voice-n7qm1z?file=/src/index.js)

Also see [Why is my React component is rendering twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48846289/why-is-my-react-component-is-rendering-twice)

Comment: Thank you ! This component comes by default with CRA and I didn't know how it worked :)