# redux actions are duplicated when I try to fetch data

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit

I am trying to create load more functionality by fetching only the necessary date i.e. the next one that needs to be added to the existing state that I have in the redux store, but I have a problem my redux actions are duplicated.

**Component App.js**

```
function App() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const data = useSelector(questionsData);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchQuestions = async () => {
      dispatch(fetchQuestionsBegin());
      try {
        const { data } = await mainUrl(`/questions?last=5`);
        return dispatch(fetchQuestionsSuccess(data));
      } catch (err) {
        return dispatch(fetchQuestionsFailure());
      }
    };
    fetchQuestions();
  }, [dispatch]);

  return (
    <>
      <div>TEST</div>
    </>
  );
}
```

**creating store**

```
const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    questionsStore: questionsReducer,
  },
});

export default store;
```

**slice**

```
const initialState = {
  loading: false,
  questions: [],
  error: "",
};

const questionsSlice = createSlice({
  name: "questions",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    fetchQuestionsBegin(state) {
      return { ...state, loading: true, error: "" };
    },
    fetchQuestionsSuccess(state, action) {
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        questions: [...state.questions, ...action.payload],
      };
    },
    fetchQuestionsFailure(state, action) {
      return { ...state, loading: false, error: action.payload };
    },
  },
});

export const { reducer: questionsReducer, actions } = questionsSlice;

export const {
  fetchQuestionsBegin,
  fetchQuestionsSuccess,
  fetchQuestionsFailure,
} = actions;
```

[redux](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2wxg.jpg)

When I exclude <React.StrictMode> everything works fine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my React component is rendering twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48846289/why-is-my-react-component-is-rendering-twice)

Comment: @SilviuBurcea it works when I comment React.StrictMode, but is there any other way to solve this ?

Comment: this is only happening on dev, what is your real concern?

Comment: is there any other solution to resolve this except comment strict mode

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [link](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects). Strict mode can cause multiple methods to invoke multiple times.  Its most likely that your redux is ran twice when the component mounts for the first time. You can implement `useRef` to detect initial mount and then conditionally render after

```
  const isMounted = useRef(false)
  useEffect(() => {
    isMounted.current = true;
  }, [])


  useEffect(() => {
    if (isMounted.current) {
       const fetchQuestions = async () => {
         dispatch(fetchQuestionsBegin());
         try {
           const { data } = await mainUrl(`/questions?last=5`);
           return dispatch(fetchQuestionsSuccess(data));
         } catch (err) {
           return dispatch(fetchQuestionsFailure());
         }
       };
       fetchQuestions();
    }
  }, [dispatch]);
```

Comment: still got same issue