# useEffect calling api's couple of times reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this useEffect function in react component. I am calling api `videoGridState` here.
Now what is happening here it is calling my api 2 times one at intitial page reaload and second one when count is changing. I want it to be called single time when page reloads. But also when `streamSearchText` changes

```
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const [streamSearchText, setStreamSearchText] = useState("");
  useEffect(() => {
    videoGridState();
  }, [count]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const delayDebounceFn = setTimeout(() => {
      setCount(count + 1);
    }, 1000);

    return () => clearTimeout(delayDebounceFn);
  }, [streamSearchText]);
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is that you have *two* `useEffect` calls, and so they're each handled, and the second triggers the first (after a delay), resulting in the duplication.

As I understand it, your goal is:

1. Run `videoGridState` **immediately** on mount, and
2. Run it again after a delay of 1000ms whenever `streamSearchText` changes

That turns out to be surprisingly awkward to do. I'd probably end up using a ref for it:

```
const firstRef = useRef(true);
const [streamSearchText, setStreamSearchText] = useState("");
useEffect(() => {
    if (firstRef.current) {
        // Mount
        videoGridState();
        firstRef.current = false;
    } else {
        // `streamSearchText` change
        const timer = setTimeout(() => {
            videoGridState();
        }, 1000);
        return () => clearTimeout(timer);
    }
}, [streamSearchText]);
```

Live Example:

```js
const { useState, useRef, useEffect } = React;

function videoGridState() {
    console.log("videoGridState ran");
}

const Example = () => {
    const firstRef = useRef(true);
    const [streamSearchText, setStreamSearchText] = useState("");
    useEffect(() => {
        if (firstRef.current) {
            // Mount
            videoGridState();
            firstRef.current = false;
        } else {
            // `streamSearchText` change
            const timer = setTimeout(() => {
                videoGridState();
            }, 1000);
            return () => clearTimeout(timer);
        }
    }, [streamSearchText]);

    return <div>
        <label>
            Search text:{" "}
            <input
                type="text"
                value={streamSearchText}
                onChange={(e) => setStreamSearchText(e.currentTarget.value)}
            />
        </label>
    </div>;
};

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<Example />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

You could also do the query immediately when `streamSearchText` is `""`, but that would happen *every time* `streamSearchText` was `""`, not just on mount. That may be good enough, depending on how rigorous you need to be.

---

**Additionally**, though, if you're still seeing something happen "on mount" twice, you may be running a development copy of the libraries with `React.StrictMode` around your app (the default in many scaffolding systems). See [this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48846289/why-is-my-react-component-is-rendering-twice) for details on how `React.StrictMode` may mount your component more than once and throw in other seeming surprises.

Comment: Seems daunting way to do that... React should have some work around on this. isn't? since the class component does able to do this in easy way?

Comment: @Profer - I wouldn't call it *daunting*. :-) There are several things that are simpler with class components than function components -- and vice versa. You have to take the rough with the smooth, in both cases.

Comment: It is going in both the condition not sure why..

Comment: @Profer - I'm not sure what you mean by that. As you can see in the live example, the `videoGridState` function runs on mount and then a second after `streamSearchText` stops changing.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer... Actually I was using React.Strictmode that is why it is rendering my component couple of times. thanks a ton

Comment: Hi why we used `"useRef"` instead we can also use a simple `let` variable?

Comment: @Profer - I don't see how you can do this with "a simple `let` variable." Can you do an example?

Answer (score 0):

Your following `useEffect()` function makes this behaviour to happen:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const delayDebounceFn = setTimeout(() => {
      setCount(count + 1);
    }, 1000);

    return () => clearTimeout(delayDebounceFn);
  }, [streamSearchText]);
```

Since it runs initially but called `setCount()` which updates the state, and forces a re-render of the component which in turn runs the first `useEffect()` since that has `[count]` in the dependency array.

And hence the cycle continues for the `[count]`

Comment: So how do they fix it and get the behavior they want?

Answer (score -1):

```js
const Example = () => {

const { useState, useRef, useEffect } = React;

// Any async function or function that returns a promise
function myDownloadAsyncFunction(data) {
console.log("222222222222222222222")
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
}

function DownloadButton() {
  const [queue, setQueue] = useState(Promise.resolve());

  onClickDownload = () => {
setQueue(queue
  .then(() => myDownloadAsyncFunction('My data'))
  .catch((err) => {console.error(err)})
)
  }

  return (
<button onClick={onClickDownload()}>Download</button>
  );
}
}
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<Example />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```