# Why components in NextJS render twice after refreshing?

Tags: javascript, next.js

I have a project NextJS. I tried log a text at the component and relize that there are always  2 lines of my log. I am wondering that my component is render 2 times, it maybe affect the performance.

My component here:

```
const PostForm = () => {
    console.log("my log");

    return (<div>abc</div>);
}
export default PostForm;
```

Logs in my browser:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's behaviour included in React in development mode. It re-renders everything twice to check for unhandled side effects and warn you about them.

Read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48846289/why-is-my-react-component-is-rendering-twice)

Answer (score -1):

If you need to have full control about side-effects you should read about the useEffect() hook. Here is a really good explanation: https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-useeffect-explanation/