# Child component rendering multiple times

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created a simple component and rendering it in `<App>` component ie parent component.
In console I see, "Inside simple component" twice.

//App.js

```js
import SimpleComponent from "./SimpleComponent";
export default function App() {
  return <SimpleComponent />;
}
```

// SimpleComponent.js

```js
  function SimpleComponent() {
   console.log("Inside simple component");
    return <div>Hello world</div>;
  }
  export default SimpleComponent;
```

Why is it rendering twice?

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/render-component-sofl-7y0hio) for above code.

Comment: Please search first. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48846289/why-is-my-react-component-is-rendering-twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48846289/why-is-my-react-component-is-rendering-twice)

Comment: While in Strict Mode, functional components will render twice to spot side effects.

However this is only going to happen in development mode.