# My components reloads before hitting the api

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, onclick

I am trying to run Update the already present data in mySQL database.

my Api calling file => helpVideosApi.js

```
export const updateHelpVideoApi = (data) => {
  const bodyData = JSON.stringify(data);
  const allParams = "updateHelpVideo";
  var apiURL = appConfig.azureFunctions.STUDY_BY_STATUS.replace("{ALLPARAMS}", allParams);
  const request = new Request(apiURL, {
    method: "POST",
    body : bodyData
  });
  return fetch(request).then(response => {
    return response.json().then(result => {
        return result;
    });
  }).catch(error => {

    return error;
  });
}
```

actions

```
export const setVideoUpdateSuccess = (response) => {
    return {
      type: "SET_VIDEO_UPDATE_SUCCESS",
      response
    }
}

export const setEmptyVideoUpdateSuccessAction = (response) => {
    return {
      type: "SET_EMPTY_VIDEO_UPDATE_SUCCESS",
      response
    }
}

export const updateHelpVideoAction = (data) =>{
    return dispatch => {
      dispatch(startSpinner());
      updateHelpVideoApi(data).then((result) => {
        dispatch(endSpinner());
        dispatch(setVideoUpdateSuccess(result));
      });
      
    }
}
```

reducer file

```
const initialState = {
   
}
const helpVideos = (state = initialState , action) =>{
    switch (action.type) {
      case 'SET_VIDEO_UPDATE_SUCCESS' :
        return{
            ...state,
            updateHelpVideoResponse : action.response
        }
      case 'SET_EMPTY_VIDEO_UPDATE_SUCCESS' :
        return{
            ...state,
            updateHelpVideoResponse : null
        }               
      default:
         return state;
      }

};


export default helpVideos;
```

main component

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Modal } from "antd";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import {
  
  updateHelpVideoAction,
  setEmptyVideoUpdateSuccessAction
} from "../../actions/helpVideos";

import { message } from 'antd';

export class UpdateHelpVideo extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        title: "",
        description: "",
        videoId: "",
        id: ""
    }
  }

  // componentDidMount() {
    
  //   this.setState({
  //     title : this.props.title,
  //     description : this.props.description,
  //     videoId : this.props.videoId,
  //     id : this.props.id
  //   })
  // }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.videoId !== prevProps.videoId || this.props.title !== prevProps.title || this.props.description !== prevProps.description || this.props.id !== prevProps.id) {
      this.setState({
        title : this.props.title,
        description : this.props.description,
        videoId : this.props.videoId,
        id : this.props.id
      })
    };
  }

  
  
  handleSubmit(e) {
    // e.preventDefault();
    const { title, description, videoId, id} = this.state;
    // const data = {};
    // data.videoId = videoId;
    // data.title = title;
    // data.description = description;
    // data.id = id;
    this.props.dispatch(updateHelpVideoAction(this.state));
    // console.log(data);
  }

  onChangeHandler(event) {
    let { name, value } = event.target;
    this.setState({
      [name]: value,
    });
  }

  // onClickHandler(event) {
  //   this.handleSubmit(event)
  // }
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if(nextProps.updateHelpVideoResponse && nextProps.updateHelpVideoResponse.success) {
        message.success(nextProps.updateHelpVideoResponse.message);
        this.props.dispatch(setEmptyVideoUpdateSuccessAction());
        // this.props.dispatch(getAllHelpVideosAction(this.state.currentPage));
        this.setState({
          title: "",
          description: "",
          videoId: "",
          id: ""
        })
    }else if(nextProps.updateHelpVideoResponse && !nextProps.updateHelpVideoResponse.success){
      message.error(nextProps.updateHelpVideoResponse.message);
      this.props.dispatch(setEmptyVideoUpdateSuccessAction());
    }
  }
  

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Modal
          title={this.props.id}
          width={750}
          footer={[
            
          ]}
          visible={this.props.showVideoModal}
          onCancel={this.props.closeVideoModal}
        >
          {/* <iframe width="700" height="400" src={"https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + this.props.videoId} title={this.props.title} frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowFullScreen>
                </iframe> */}
          <div id="">
            <div className="row d-flex justify-content-between">
              <div className="col-md-12 form-wrapper">
                <form  onSubmit={(e) => this.handleSubmit(e)} >
                  <div class="form-group margin-bottom">
                    <label htmlFor="title">Title</label>
                    <input
                      className="form-control"
                      type="text"
                      name="title"
                      value={this.state.title || ""}
                      onChange={(e) => this.onChangeHandler(e)}
                      placeholder={this.state.title}
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group ">
                    <label htmlFor="description">Description</label>
                    <textarea
                      type="text"
                      rows="4"
                      className="vimeo-desc form-control "
                      name="description"
                      value={this.state.description || ""}
                      onChange={(e) => this.onChangeHandler(e)}
                      placeholder="Enter description of the video"
                    ></textarea>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="file">Enter Video ID</label>
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      name="videoId"
                      className="form-control"
                      value={this.state.videoId || ""}
                      placeholder="Enter videoId"
                      onChange={(e) => this.onChangeHandler(e)}
                    />
                  </div>
                  <button  name="submit" className="btn btn-primary form-control" >UPDATE</button>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </Modal>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps=(state) =>{
    return{
      
      updateHelpVideoResponse: state.helpVideos.updateHelpVideoResponse
    }
}

export default  connect(mapStateToProps)(UpdateHelpVideo) ;
```

file from where I am entering the main file and passing some data to be used in main file.

import React, { Component } from "react";

//redux
import { connect } from "react-redux";

//Actions

```
import {
  getAllHelpVideosAction,
  deleteHelpVideoAction,
  setEmplteDeleteHelpVideosAction,
  updateHelpVideoAction,
  setVideoUpdateSuccess,
  setEmptyVideoUpdateSuccessAction
} from "../../actions/helpVideos";

//Components
import { UpdateHelpVideo } from "../../components/updateHelpVideo";


//Others
import Pagination from "react-js-pagination";
import deletebutton from "../../Images/delete_ico.svg";
import subMenu from "../../Images/kebab_menu.png";
import projectedit from "../../Images/update_ico.svg";
import { Button } from "reactstrap";
import { injectIntl, FormattedMessage } from "react-intl";

class VideoDataTable extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      videoList: [],
      totalPages: 0,
      showVideoModal:false,
      watchedVideoId: null,
      watchedVideoDescription: null,
      watchedTitle: null,
      watchedId:null
    };
    this.handlePageChange = this.handlePageChange.bind(this);
    this.closeVideoModal = this.closeVideoModal.bind(this);
    this.openVideoModal = this.openVideoModal.bind(this);
    this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
  }

  toggle() {
    this.setState({
      modal: !this.state.modal,
    });
  }

  closeVideoModal(){
    this.setState({showVideoModal:false})
  }

  openVideoModal(title, description, videoId, id){
    this.setState({showVideoModal:true, watchedTitle:title, watchedVideoDescription:description, watchedVideoId:videoId, watchedId:id})
    // const { title, description, videoId, id} = this.state;
    // const data = {};
    // data.videoId = videoId;
    // data.title = title;
    // data.description = description;
    // data.id = id;
    // this.props.dispatch(updateHelpVideoAction(data));
  }

  softDelete(id) {
    this.props.dispatch(deleteHelpVideoAction(id));
  }
  handlePageChange(pageNumber) {
    this.props.setCurrentPage(pageNumber);
    this.props.dispatch(getAllHelpVideosAction(pageNumber));
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.dispatch(getAllHelpVideosAction(this.props.currentPage));
  }
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    console.log(nextProps);
    if (nextProps.getAllHelpVideos && nextProps.getAllHelpVideos.success) {
      this.setState({
        videoList: nextProps.getAllHelpVideos.data,
        totalPages: nextProps.getAllHelpVideos.totalRecord,
      });
    }
    if (
      nextProps.getDeleteVideoResponse &&
      nextProps.getDeleteVideoResponse.success
    ) {
      alert(nextProps.getDeleteVideoResponse.message);
      this.props.dispatch(setEmplteDeleteHelpVideosAction());
      this.props.setCurrentPage(1);
      this.props.dispatch(getAllHelpVideosAction(1));
    }

    if(
      nextProps.getUpdateVideoResponse && 
      nextProps.getUpdateVideoResponse.success
    ){
      alert(nextProps.getUpdateVideoResponse.message);
      this.props.dispatch(setEmptyVideoUpdateSuccessAction());
      this.props.dispatch(getAllHelpVideosAction(1));
    }
  }
  render() {
    const { intl } = this.props;
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div className="p-3 bg-white rounded" id="video-data-table">
          <div className="table-responsive role-list ">
            <table className="table table-co-layout1 table-striped">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th id="tblh">#</th>
                  <th id="tbhleft">
                    {intl.formatMessage({ id: "helpVideo.helpVideoTdTitle" })}
                  </th>
                  <th id="tblh">
                    {intl.formatMessage({
                      id: "helpVideo.helpVideoTdDescription",
                    })}
                  </th>
                  <th id="tblh">
                    {intl.formatMessage({ id: "helpVideo.helpVideoTdVideo" })}
                  </th>
                  {/* <th id="tblh"></th> */}
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody className="video-list">
                {this.state.videoList.length > 0 ? (
                  this.state.videoList.map((d, i) => (
                    <tr key={i}>
                      <td>
                        {/* <Button
                          className="delete-btn"
                          onClick={this.softDelete.bind(this, d.id)}
                        >
                          <img
                            style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
                            src={deletebutton}
                            height="20px"
                            width="20px"
                            alt=""
                          />
                          Delete
                        </Button> */}
                        <div class="dropdown">
                          {/* <button
                            class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle"
                            type="button"
                            id="dropdownMenuButton"
                            data-toggle="dropdown"
                            aria-haspopup="true"
                            aria-expanded="false"
                          >
                            Dropdown button
                          </button> */}
                          <a
                            className="edit-btn"
                            id="dropdownMenuButton"
                            data-toggle="dropdown"
                            aria-haspopup="true"
                            aria-expanded="false"
                          >
                            <img
                              style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
                              src={subMenu}
                              height="30px"
                              width="30px"
                              alt=""
                            />
                          </a>
                          <div
                            class="dropdown-menu"
                            aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton"
                          >
                            <a
                              className=" dropdown-item "
                              onClick={this.softDelete.bind(this, d.id)}
                            >
                              Delete
                            </a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item"  onClick={() => this.openVideoModal(d.title, d.description, d.viemo_video_id, d.id)}>
                              Update
                            </a>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </td>
                      <td>{d.title}</td>
                      <td>{d.description}</td>
                      <td>
                        <a
                          href={d.viemo_video_id}
                          target="_blank"
                          style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
                        >
                          {d.viemo_video_id}
                        </a>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  ))
                ) : (
                  <p className="text-center">Data not found</p>
                )}
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
          <div
            id="pageinationstyle"
            className="pagination-container--helpVideo  rounded"
          >
            {this.state.totalPages > 0 ? (
              <Pagination
                activePage={this.props.currentPage}
                itemsCountPerPage={10}
                totalItemsCount={this.state.totalPages}
                pageRangeDisplayed={5}
                onChange={this.handlePageChange}
              />
            ) : (
              ""
            )}
          </div>
          
        </div>
        <UpdateHelpVideo
          showVideoModal={this.state.showVideoModal} 
          title={this.state.watchedTitle}
          description={this.state.watchedVideoDescription}
          videoId={this.state.watchedVideoId}
          id={this.state.watchedId}
          closeVideoModal={this.closeVideoModal}
        />
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    getAllHelpVideos: state.helpVideos.getAllHelpVideosResponse,
    getDeleteVideoResponse: state.helpVideos.getDeleteVideoResponse,
    getUpdateVideoResponse: state.helpVideos.getUpdateVideoResponse
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(injectIntl(VideoDataTable));
```

Comment: I see you paste a lot of code. But what’s wrong? Where you want us to check?

Comment: Why shouldn't your component update before api call?

Comment: After dipatching it goes to the updateHelpVideoAction in which I am trying to make api Call but just before that component reloads and it never hits the api

Comment: It never goes inside the api calling file.

Comment: React 16 causes loading twice in Strict mode. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48846289/why-is-my-react-component-is-rendering-twice