# run componentDidUpdate in functional react without changing

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, react-functional-component

this is my app :

```
function ManageUsers(){
  const [refreshpage  , setrefreshpage ] = useState(0);
  
  const handerefreshpage = () => {
       console.log(refreshpage);
       setrefreshpage(refreshpage+1);
    }
    
  useEffect( () => {
        // ManageUsers run useEffect as mounting
        console.log('ManageUsers run useEffect --> componentDidMount');
    } , [] );
    
  useEffect( () => {
        // ManageUsers run useEffect --> componentDidUpdate
        console.log('ManageUsers run useEffect --> componentDidUpdate');

    } , [refreshpage] );
    
    return(
```

.....
)
export default ManageUsers;

but when I run my app componentDidUpdate run without changing 'refreshpage'

[image]

Comment: You may be running the app in Strict Mode. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/48846289/994006

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make React useEffect hook not run on initial render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53253940/make-react-useeffect-hook-not-run-on-initial-render)

Answer (score 3):

The `useEffect` hook can be used as the combined version of `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate`. For that you need to do the some logic inside the hook as per your needs:

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (refreshpage > 0) {
      // ManageUsers run useEffect --> componentDidUpdate
      console.log("ManageUsers run useEffect --> componentDidUpdate");
    } else {
      // ManageUsers run useEffect as mounting
      console.log("ManageUsers run useEffect --> componentDidMount");
    }
  }, [refreshpage]);
```

```js
function App() {
  const [refreshpage, setrefreshpage] = React.useState(0);

  const handerefreshpage = () => {
    setrefreshpage(refreshpage + 1);
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (refreshpage > 0) {
      // ManageUsers run useEffect --> componentDidUpdate
      console.log("ManageUsers run useEffect --> componentDidUpdate");
    } else {
      // ManageUsers run useEffect as mounting
      console.log("ManageUsers run useEffect --> componentDidMount");
    }
  }, [refreshpage]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={handerefreshpage}>Refresh</button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`useEffect(fn,[])` with an empty callback will be called after mounting (like componenDidMount).

When you do `useEffect(fn,[refreshPage])`, the `fn` callback is run on the first time too. That is because all effects are run on the first time (unless you do some customization). This is given in the docs :

> Does useEffect run after every render? Yes! By default, it runs both after the first render and after every update.

Think of it like earlier there was no value in `refreshPage` and now it has some value `0`, so the effect is run.

You can check for your condition inside the useEffect as mentioned in the other answer.
I have created a simple [hook](https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-fog-utn2sr) to mimick the update functionality

```
const { useRef, useEffect } = require("react");

const useUpdate = (callback, arr) => {
  const initRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    let returnedValue = null;
    if (!initRef.current) {
      initRef.current = true;
    } else {
      returnedValue = callback();
    }
    if (returnedValue) {
      return returnedValue();
    }
  }, arr);
};
export default useUpdate;
```

Use it like `useEffect`, but it does not run on `componentDidMount`.