# Why do I get double logs in my React app?

Tags: reactjs

I'm getting double logs in my app and not sure what that second log is. I've minimized everything in this component just to try and understand why it is doubled up but I can't understand. It doesn't look like it actually logs twice though like what is this source `VM236`? When it's only one log it's not that big of a deal but when I have more it really starts cluttering things up.

This is the component (really nothing there:

```
import { HomePresentational } from "../presentational";

export const HomeContainer = () => {
  console.log("Just a check log");

  return <HomePresentational itineraries={[]} />;
};
```

And this is what I'm seeing

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my React component is rendering twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48846289/why-is-my-react-component-is-rendering-twice)

Comment: @jonrsharpe no. I don't think it renders twice. Tried to remove the strict mode anyway and it made no difference.

Comment: Then please give a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

You are running your React app in [strict mode](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html), just go to "index.js" and remove strict React.StrictMode tag.

```
 <React.StrictMode>
 </App>
 </React.StrictMode>
```

Comment: That's not it. Still getting the exact same logs. It doesn't look like the second log is from a second render anyway the source for the log is something else other than my component (VM369).

Comment: try to search for "console.log" in your code may you will find one that you had  forget about