# The function of my code runs twice instead of once?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

`

```
import './App.css';
import ArrayState from './components/ArrayState';
import FetchApi from './components/FetchAPI/FetchApi';
import Login from './components/Login';
import Useeffect2 from './components/Useeffect2';
import UseEffects from './components/UseEffects';
import React,{useEffect} from 'react'


function App() {
  const getUsers = async() => {
       console.log("function")
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        
    console.log("use")
        
        getUsers();
    });
  return (
  //  <ArrayState/>
  // <Login/>
  // <UseEffects/>
  // <Useeffect2/>
  <FetchApi/>
  );
}

export default App;
```

[image: the result of code in image below]

the function "getUsers" is called once in "UseState" but its runs 2 times. i want to run function once. i have define body of function into useEffect?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my React component is rendering twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48846289/why-is-my-react-component-is-rendering-twice)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [useEffect is running twice on mount in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72238175/useeffect-is-running-twice-on-mount-in-react)

Answer (score 1):

add empty array to the useEffect, so that it only make calls on page first load

```
 useEffect(() => {
        const getUsers = async() => {
       console.log("function")
    }
    console.log("use")
        
        getUsers();
    }, []);
```

Comment: i done but it not works

Comment: edited check again

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an empty array as the second argument to the useEffect hook :

```
useEffect(() => {
  // Side Effect
}, []);
```

In this case, the side effect runs only once after the initial render of the component.

Comment: i done but it not works

Answer (score 0):

Already [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48846289/why-is-my-react-component-is-rendering-twice)

You need to provide an dependency array

```
useEffect(() => {


}, []) // dependency array with props, variable that trigger the side effect
```

even this will run [twice in development](https://beta.reactjs.org/apis/react/useEffect#my-effect-runs-after-every-re-render) due to stritct mode, which helps is catching bugs related to cleanup
but if you want to disable it (not recommended)

```
    // generally in index.js
    ReactDOM.render(
      <React.StrictMode> // remove this to disable stritct mode
        <App />
      </React.StrictMode>,
   document.getElementById('root')
```

Comment: it does not work

Comment: I edited the answer to be more clear

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `React 18` and your app is wrapped in the `<StrictMode>` tag, then this is expected behavior added on purpose in the hopes to help devs catch bugs relevant to the lifecycle of their components, such as abusing/misusing the `useEffect` hook.

What the new `StrictMode` actually does is unmount and then remount every component once it gets rendered.

Resulting in an initial lifecycle that looks like this:

```
* React mounts the component.
  * Layout effects are created.
  * Effects are created.
* React simulates unmounting the component.
  * Layout effects are destroyed.
  * Effects are destroyed.
* React simulates mounting the component with the previous state.
  * Layout effects are created.
  * Effects are created.
```

Note that it only behaves this way in dev environment, and not in the production build.

**ref:** https://reactjs.org/blog/2022/03/29/react-v18.html#new-strict-mode-behaviors

---

P.S. you should also add the empty dependency array as mentioned in other comments, otherwise it will also run every time the component re-renders.