# Removing "React Strict Mode" solved my error. Is this is a budge?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-strictmode

I've found [Why is my React component is rendering twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48846289/why-is-my-react-component-is-rendering-twice) which fixed my coding error (setState getting called X times depending in which component it gets called), but do I have a problem with my code now if removing React.StrictMode solved it?

Someone wrote:

> This happens is an intentional feature of the React.StrictMode. It only happens in development mode and should help to find accidental side effects in the render phase.

Comment: Yes if you had a bug that got solved by removing strict mode, it's still a bug. Rendering multiple times is by design, let React do that.

Comment: If Removing Strict mode solved your issue, that is a warning that you will have those bugs in production (real-world usage). So, you should fix your code in such a way that the bugs do not appear even in development.