# ReactJs why do i get two console logs in a simple component?

Tags: reactjs, nav

i have this simple nav component, but it drives me crazy because it makes every console log i make in the app two times.
Im new to React btw.

```
export const NavBar = () => {
  const [showNav, setShowNav] = useState(false);

  const handleNavClick = () => {
    setShowNav(!showNav);
  };

  console.log("hi");

  return (
    <>
      <nav className="flex items-center justify-between pl-8 pr-16 fixed w-full border h-20 top-0 bg-white/30 backdrop-blur-sm z-10">
        {/* Logo */}
        <img
          src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dv8nczwtj/image/upload/v1684896617/Logo_jivlnb.png"
          alt="Logo"
          className="logo"
        />
        {/* Nav WEB*/}
        <div className="md:flex flex-row space-x-5 hidden">
          <a href="#" className="brand">
            Apple
          </a>
          <a href="#" className="brand">
            Samsung
          </a>
          <a href="#" className="brand">
            Xiaomi
          </a>
          <a href="#" className="brand">
            Google
          </a>
        </div>
        {/* BTN Nav Mobil */}
        <button className="md:hidden" onClick={handleNavClick}>
          <img
            src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dv8nczwtj/image/upload/v1684859901/menu_wh8ccz.png"
            alt="Menu"
            className="w-6"
          />
        </button>
        {/* Cart */}
        <CartWidget />
      </nav>
      {/* Nav Mobil */}
      {showNav && (
        <div
          className="flex fixed w-full flex-col justify-center items-center space-y-4 pb-2 border-b-2 border-black md:hidden bg-white/30 top-20 pt-4 backdrop-blur-sm"
          style={{ animation: "fadeIn .5s linear" }}
        >
          <a href="#" className="brand">
            Apple
          </a>
          <a href="#" className="brand">
            Samsung
          </a>
          <a href="#" className="brand">
            Xiaomi
          </a>
          <a href="#" className="brand">
            Google
          </a>
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
};
```

[double console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9R7zO.png)

I have tried putting the handleClick function in a useEffect but then when i put it on the onClick it says that the function is never declared

Comment: Is the code perhaps [running in strict mode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48846289/328193)?

Comment: It was the strict mode thing. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your app using `React.StrictMode` (https://react.dev/reference/react/StrictMode#fixing-bugs-found-by-double-rendering-in-development) ?