# Double Rendering Issue using Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am experiencing an issue with double rendering in my Next.js application. I'm using next 13, when I run next dev, my page always rendered twice:

```
// the project is just result of `create-next-app`
// pages/index.js
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

export default function Home() {
  console.log('render')

  const [state, setState] = useState(() => {
    console.log('state initialize');
    return 'state';
  })

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      console.log('unmounted')
    }
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      Home
    </div>
  )
}
```

[image]

even lazy state intialize twice, and unmount last. So I think it is not remounted, but create twice.
However, next build && next start is okay and render once.

**Expected Behavior**

Render, and Initialize Once with next dev

**Note**

Because this question has association with [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72238175/why-useeffect-running-twice-and-how-to-handle-it-well-in-react), it may seem to be answered. But there is a difference in its resolution with respect to dealing with it in nextjs.

Comment: This is the default behavior for React in dev strict mode https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48846289/why-is-my-react-component-is-rendering-twice

Comment: And it's there to let you know you're doing something wrong (like updating the component _while_ it's rendering).

Answer (score 1):

Since next is a framework that is based on React, it is bound to its functionality. And this is intended in React 18 with Strict Mode (FYI: https://reactjs.org/blog/2022/03/08/react-18-upgrade-guide.html#updates-to-strict-mode). You can find a workaround here ([reactwg/react-18#18](https://github.com/reactwg/react-18/discussions/18))

Strict Mode is a feature that helps identify and correct problems in React applications earlier and more effectively. When Strict Mode is enabled, React performs additional checks and warns about practices that can lead to errors and performance problems.

Knowing this. It is possible to disable strict mode from `next.config.js` using

`reactStrictMode: false`

[image]

[Next.js docs ref for strictMode toggling](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/react-strict-mode)

Related: [Why is my React component is rendering twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48846289/why-is-my-react-component-is-rendering-twice)